# Strongly typed events package for typescript. How to add bound handelers to an event

Tags: typescript, events, strongly-typed-dataset

I'm using the [strongly typed events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strongly-typed-events) package in my app. This package is really useful for its events and how it handles those. I used the package like this for my app.

```
let onUpdate = new SignalDispatcher = new SignalDispatcher();
let component = new Component();
onUpdate.sub(component.Update);

void Update(){
 this.onUpdate.dispatch();
}

class Component {
 public Update(){
  //do stuff
 }
}
```

This works for one thing only. If you try to access "this" in the component update function. You won't get the component but the event. So I tried the function.bind(component) method like this.

```
onUpdate.sub(component.Update.bind(component));
```

This is a solution but now I have a problem unsubscribing. If I try to unsub the exact same bound method, the same way you would like a normal method, it would not unsubscribe. My guess is that it can't compare bound methods to each other. This always results in my method still subscribed.

Any alternatives or solutions I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code, that library confuses callback functions for subscription signatures.

Within a proper `subscribe->cancel` architecture, method `subscribe` should always return a `Subscription` object, to allow a safe way to cancel the subscription.

Since the question has been open for awhile, I will suggest an alternative events library [sub-events](https://github.com/vitaly-t/sub-events) for your consideration.

Specifically for signals, as per the [Signals](https://github.com/vitaly-t/sub-events/wiki/Signals) page there, we can define a generic signal type:

```
class Signal extends SubEvent<void> {} // reusable Signal type
```

Then we can update your code to this:

```
const onUpdate = new Signal();

const component = new Component();

// you can bind an event to the right context in 2 ways:
const sub = onUpdate.subscribe(component.Update.bind(component));
// or alternatively:
const sub = onUpdate.subscribe(component.Update, {thisArg: component});


void Update() {
    this.onUpdate.emit(); // emit the event (signal)
}

class Component {
    public Update(){
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

And then whenever you need to cancel the subscription, you just do this:

```
sub.cancel();
```